# Kubernetes ingress service NodePort is only listen to tcp6/ipv6 not tcp/ipv4

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have setup ingress-nginx using helm through `helm install --name x2f1 stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-nginx` and service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: x2f1-ingress-nginx-svc
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30443
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
```

running svc and po's:

```
[ottuser@ottorc01 ~]$ kubectl get svc,po -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/x2f1-ingress-nginx-svc               NodePort       192.168.34.116    <none>        80:30080/TCP,443:30443/TCP   2d18h
service/x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   192.168.188.188   <pending>     80:32427/TCP,443:31726/TCP   2d18h
service/x2f1-nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      192.168.156.175   <none>        80/TCP                       2d18h

NAME                                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller-cd5fbd447-c4fqm         1/1     Running   0          2d18h
pod/x2f1-nginx-ingress-default-backend-67f8db4966-nlgdd   1/1     Running   0          2d18h
```

after that my nodePort: 30080 is only available against tcp6, due to this, im facing connection refused when try to access from other vm.

```
[ottuser@ottorc01 ~]$ netstat -tln | grep '30080'
tcp6       3      0 :::30080                :::*                    LISTEN
```

```
[ottuser@ottwrk02 ~]$ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6443          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.18.0.10:2379         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.18.0.10:2380         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33372         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::30443                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::32427                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::31726                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::30462                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::30080                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Logs from `pod/x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller-cd5fbd447-c4fqm`:

```
[ottuser@ottorc01 ~]$ kubectl logs pod/x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller-cd5fbd447-c4fqm -n ingress-nginx --tail 50
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.24.1
  Build:      git-ce418168f
  Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I0621 11:48:26.952213       6 flags.go:185] Watching for Ingress class: nginx
W0621 11:48:26.952772       6 flags.go:214] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
nginx version: nginx/1.15.10
W0621 11:48:26.961458       6 client_config.go:549] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0621 11:48:26.961913       6 main.go:205] Creating API client for https://192.168.0.1:443
I0621 11:48:26.980673       6 main.go:249] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.14 (v1.14.1) - git (clean) commit b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290 - platform linux/amd64
I0621 11:48:26.986341       6 main.go:102] Validated ingress-nginx/x2f1-nginx-ingress-default-backend as the default backend.
I0621 11:48:27.339581       6 main.go:124] Created fake certificate with PemFileName: /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem
I0621 11:48:27.384666       6 nginx.go:265] Starting NGINX Ingress controller
I0621 11:48:27.403396       6 event.go:209] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller", UID:"89b4caf0-941a-11e9-a0fb-005056010a71", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1347806", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller
I0621 11:48:28.585472       6 nginx.go:311] Starting NGINX process
I0621 11:48:28.585630       6 leaderelection.go:217] attempting to acquire leader lease  ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
W0621 11:48:28.586778       6 controller.go:373] Service "ingress-nginx/x2f1-nginx-ingress-default-backend" does not have any active Endpoint
I0621 11:48:28.586878       6 controller.go:170] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0621 11:48:28.592786       6 status.go:86] new leader elected: x2f1-ngin-nginx-ingress-controller-567f495994-hmcqq
I0621 11:48:28.761600       6 controller.go:188] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0621 11:48:28.761677       6 controller.go:202] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
[21/Jun/2019:11:48:29 +0000]TCP200000.001
W0621 11:48:32.444623       6 controller.go:373] Service "ingress-nginx/x2f1-nginx-ingress-default-backend" does not have any active Endpoint
[21/Jun/2019:11:48:35 +0000]TCP200000.000
I0621 11:49:05.793313       6 status.go:86] new leader elected: x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller-cd5fbd447-c4fqm
I0621 11:49:05.793331       6 leaderelection.go:227] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0621 11:53:08.579333       6 controller.go:170] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0621 11:53:08.579639       6 event.go:209] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"ott", Name:"hie-01-hie", UID:"32678e25-941b-11e9-a0fb-005056010a71", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1348532", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress ott/hie-01-hie
I0621 11:53:08.764204       6 controller.go:188] Backend successfully reloaded.
[21/Jun/2019:11:53:08 +0000]TCP200000.000
I0621 11:54:05.812798       6 status.go:295] updating Ingress ott/hie-01-hie status from [] to [{ }]
```

```
[ottuser@ottorc01 ~]$ sudo ss -l -t -p | grep 30080
LISTEN     3      128       :::30080                   :::*                     users:(("kube-proxy",pid=29346,fd=15))
```

Is there any way to debug it in further depth or add that port to tcp/ipv4. If still something unclear from my side let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem and wish to know if a solution has been found. Thanks.

Comment: @dharmatron you have to make sure ingress service is running which has node port in it configuration. and service name should be same as it getting calls from nginx ingress controller.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem of the tcp6.

On most modern Linux distros, including Container Linux, listening on 
tcp6 will also imply tcp4.

The issue itself is with your `x2f1-ingress-nginx-svc` service and specifically with selectors, which do not match with any pod

```
selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

If you will do

```
kubectl get ep -n ingress-nginx
```

you will see that there's no endpoints for that service

```
NAME                                 ENDPOINTS                        AGE
x2f1-ingress-nginx-svc               <none>                           13m
```

Now the question is what do you want to expose with this service?

For instance, if you will be exposing `x2f1-nginx-ingress-controller` (even though helm already created appropriate service), your yaml should be like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: x2f1-ingress-nginx-svc
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30443
  selector:
     app: nginx-ingress
     component: controller
```